# Cannot GET /simple_pages/about (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a test app from scratch in Ruby on Rails. It keep getting a "Cannot GET" error when trying to view the pages locally (local:3000). Here is a screen shot - https://snag.gy/FidPCx.jpg. When I access local:3000 direct I get this - https://snag.gy/EosGOu.jpg

The problem started when I had someone help me fix some code on my git repo. Here is a link to my repo - https://github.com/Kevin-Meldau75/test_app

I've done a search on Stack and they suggest that I update my Gems. I've done this and it's not worked.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm very new to RoR so I may of missed a very basic step.

Kevin

Comment: Show the server log here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I clone the repo and get the response right (in linux)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the methods that will connect to the views in the `views/simple_pages` directory.  I am adding the contact method because that will produce the same error if you do not fix it. Add this into the `simple_pages` controller

```
def about
end

def contact
end
```

So the end result will be

```
class SimplePagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

For each page you will need a corresponding method in the controller.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me so fast!

I've tried that, please see https://snag.gy/DzeGkM.jpg
I'm still getting the same result - https://snag.gy/k6VZPp.jpg

Kevin

Comment: what is the output of running `rake routes` from your terminal, can you post that in the original question please.  Also, even if it doe snot fix your issue you do need to add these methods into the controller either way.